# flatten json object using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have the following json object:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "activities":[
       {"time":1659800397,"cities":["london","paris"],"type":1},
       {"time":1659800411,"cities":["rome"],          "type":2}
     ]
}
```

I would like to flatten it to the following tab separated structure, perhaps using jq

| id | time | cities | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1659800397 | london | 1 |
| 1 | 1659800397 | paris | 1 |
| 1 | 1659800411 | rome | 2 |

Comment: Here is the final code I used to achieve that.
jq -r '.id as $id | .activities[] | "\($id);\(.time);\(.type);\(.cities[])"' input.json

Answer (score 2):

Either store values in variables for reference before descending deeper into the structure:

```bash
. as {$id} | .activities[] | .cities[] as $city
| [$id, .time, $city, .type] | @tsv
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8rpu-v9t-WK)

Or add the final pieces together while iterating over the parts separately:

```bash
[.id] + (.activities[] | [.time] + (.cities[] | [.]) + [.type]) | @tsv
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/aC34_rbrW88)

Output:

```
1   1659800397  london  1
1   1659800397  paris   1
1   1659800411  rome    2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself; however, I think it could be useful to others:

```
jq -r '.id as $id | .activities[] | "\($id);\(.time);\(.type);\(.cities[])"' input.json
```

Here's how the code works:

`.id as $id` extracts the "id" field and assigns it to the variable, `$id`.
`.activities[]` iterates over each object in the "activities" array.
`"...\($id);\(.time);\(.type);\(.cities[])"` constructs the desired output format with the extracted values, using the variables and fields we defined.